# How to display progress bar when downloading files in nwjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

I am creating a NWJS app which needs to download some files from a url and I need to display a progress bar to display the progress of the download.

My current code just downloads the file but does not display and update a progress bar and I am wondering how this can be done.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var file = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);

var request = https.get(fileurl, function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    $('#progressbar_upload').addClass('bg-success');
    uploadDone();
});
```

This just downloads the file and then changes the color of the progress bar when the download is complete. I want it to change the width of the progress bar to show the progress of the download as it is downloading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the total `content-length` from the `response` to get total download size and when it returns `data` to `data` event. Finally you can get its length and can calculate the download percentage as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var file = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);

var contentLength;
var length;
var responseData = '';
var request = https.get(fileurl, function (response) {
    contentLength = parseInt(response.headers['content-length']); // in bytes
    length = [];

    // Grab the data buffer of the request
    response.on('data', (d) => {
        responseData += d;
        length.push(d.length);
        let sum = length.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        let completedParcentage = (sum / contentLength) * 100;
        console.log(`completed reading ${sum} bytes out of ${contentLength} bytes`);
        console.log(`${completedParcentage} percentage of download complete`);

        // Modify this to alter the width of progress-bar using percentageCompleted
        $('#progressbar_upload').addClass('bg-success');
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
        file.write(responseData);
        uploadDone();
    })

});
```

Comment: this is not working. it seems that response.on('end') is not firing.

Comment: You will get the percentage of download complete when `data` is sent to `data` event, you need to use calculated `completedParcentage` within `data` event to alter the `progress-bar` width.